# Binding Android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

A common approach for checking if you have bounded to a service in Android is keeping a boolean parameter such as `mBound` in your binding steps as described in Android developers guide. I noticed a problem in this Android reference tutorial and I think this approach is somehow a bad practice. Here is the code from [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

Here is a code block with language code as hint:

```java
public class ActivityMessenger extends Activity {
    Messenger mService = null;
    boolean mBound;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mService = new Messenger(service);
            mBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mService = null;
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to the service
        bindService(new Intent(this, MessengerService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, Here is the problem. Let's assume that for any reason `OnStop()` is called immediately after `OnStart()`. You can create this situation by placing a breakpoint in `OnCreate()` and wait for your phone screen goes dark that forces an application recreation and then continue application run.

If this situation happens, the `mBount` variable will be still `false` when you run `OnStop()`, because service connection's `onServiceConnected()` is not called yet. So you will not call `unbindService()` and you will have a service that you have binded and never unbinded.

Any suggestions for a better approach for Binding services? I wonder if calling `unbideService()` in any situation is enough or not(for example calling even though service is not binded right now).

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this in practice, but it seems reasonable to set `mBound = true` already when *calling* `bindService` instead of in the callback. Actually, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding) says that you should call `unbindService` even if `bindService` returned `false` (meaning you would never get any `onServiceConnected` call and `mBound` would never be true):

> Note: If the method returns false, your client does not have a valid
>   connection to the service. However, your client should still call
>   unbindService(); otherwise, your client will keep the service from
>   shutting down when it is idle.

With this in mind it's clear that only setting `mBound = true` in `onServiceConnected` is not sufficient (or at least recommended). I would suspect that calling `unbindService` when not previously bound is a no-op, but that might need some confirmation. If so, setting `mBound = true` when calling `bindService` seems like a good approach.

Comment: `mBound` is normally used to notice complete connection to service which show your `Messenger` is ready to use or you may cause exceptions by accessing `Messenger`. But it seems that you are somehow right about calling `unbindService()`. So I guess it may be better to always call `unbindService()` in `onStop()` without checking `mBound` and leave setting `mBound = true` for `onServiceConnected` to prevent exceptions for accessing `Messenger`.